# why is my eventListener called multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, event-handling

```
function form_anim(){

    form_2.style.transform = "translateX(0)"
    form_2.style.transition = "transform 400ms"
}
previous.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    form_2.style.transform = "translateX(900px)";
    form_2.style.transition = "transform 400ms"
    form_holder.classList.toggle('anim2');
})

//let n = 1;

submit_1.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    //n=1;

    form_holder.classList.toggle('anim');
    form_holder.addEventListener('animationend',()=>{

       
        form_2.style.transform = "translateX(0)"
        form_2.style.transition = "transform 200ms"

    })
});
```

I am trying to create 3 forms each has the next and previous buttons. When the next button is clicked, the first form should scale to 0, and form 2 should translate X(0px), initially set as 900px. It works the first time perfectly but when the previous is clicked the 2nd form translates to 900px but then comes back to 0px.

Comment: which event listener?

Comment: You add another listener every time you click. So if you click three times, you'd get three event listeners and each will be triggered on animationend.

Comment: @JaromandaX the animationend event listener

Comment: @VLAZ ok lemme have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add a new event listener every time when submit_1 button is clicked. When you click the button second time the event listener added on the first click will also run
Try using this code:

```js
form_holder.addEventListener('animationend',()=>{
        form_2.style.transform = "translateX(0)"
        form_2.style.transition = "transform 200ms"
});

function form_anim(){
    form_2.style.transform = "translateX(0)"
    form_2.style.transition = "transform 400ms"
}
previous.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    form_2.style.transform = "translateX(900px)";
    form_2.style.transition = "transform 400ms"
    form_holder.classList.toggle('anim2');
})

//let n = 1;

submit_1.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    //n=1;
    form_holder.classList.toggle('anim');
});
```

Comment: Bro, it's showing the same result I will link a Jsfiddle file so everyone can see the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding RemoveEventlsitener inside the form_holder function works well thank you all for spending your valuable time trying to answer my question.